# Why does javascript evaluate multiple AND criterias if first criteria failed

Tags: javascript, evaluation

Is it really true that javascript evaluates further into a multiple AND criteria statement, even though the first condition failed ?

I have the following statement:

```
if(data.equipment_notifications != "undefined" && data.equipment_notifications.length > 0)
```

I assumed that the condition would fail at the initial criteria, and not even try to evaluate the second because if the first fails (false) the whole condition will always be false when it comes to AND so it would skip an move along.

But i get "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" which indicates that it does not skip after the first failed criteria.

**Question:** Is it true that javascript will evaluate the whole criteria of a statement, even if failing the first and be bound to fail the whole statement no matter the evaluation of the remaining criteria(s) ?

**Update:** The answer given is true when it comes to evaluation of expressions in javascript. Furthermore i found that i made a stupid mistake of forgetting typeof in my test for "undefined"

```
if(typeof data.equipment_notifications != "undefined" &&    data.equipment_notifications.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does javascript evaluate multiple AND criterias if first criteria failed

It doesn't.

> Is it true that javascript will evaluate the whole criteria of a statement, even if failing the first and be bound to fail the whole statement no matter the evaluation of the remaining criteria(s)?

No, it's not true. JavaScript uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

This is trivially easy to prove to yourself:

```
function a() { alert('a'); return false}
function b() { alert('b'); return true }

if (a() && b()) { alert('c') }
```

If JavaScript "evaluated the whole exression", it would alert both `a` and `b`. But, because the first operand of the `&&` is false, JavaScript does not evaluate the second.

---

> But i get "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" which indicates that it does not skip after the first failed criteria.

No, that is not at all what this indicates. You're testing for the **string** `"undefined"`. `undefined` and `"undefined"` are two very different things.

Comment: Your right .. i found the bug in my statement. I was also missing a typeof at the beginning of my first criteria .. But .. thanks for the help and for the enlightment about javascript evaluation :)